# How do I hook into a service with OpenCover?

Tags: .net, windows, service, code-coverage, opencover

As a part of code coverage testing, I need to test several services. The OpenCover github mentions the ability to do this (Issue #36), but doesn't tell you how. The wiki "Usage" page doesn't mention anything about this. `opencover -?` brings up a mention of the `-service` switch, without any description of what it does, exactly or how to use it. Can anyone tell me how this switch works and how I can hook into a service with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) you will find that there is a document called Usage.rtf that describes how to use OpenCover against a service.

Basically you have to run OpenCover under an Administration account with pre-registered Profilers (use regsvr32). The service switch should supply the name of the service.

It is quite tricky to do which is why I recommend you create your service with a console mode of operation as then doing coverage under a normal user account has less restrictions and is much easier to setup.

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question, when doing a coverage test for a service, how do I specify the PDBs? Using `-targetdir` doesn't work, even after moving the PDBs to a simple directory like "C:\".

Comment: You should be able to keep the PDBs in the same folder as the service - that is how it has worked for me. If it isn't working as expected, please raise the issue as a bug on GitHub; preferably with a sample that helps replicate the issue.